# External CSS font family not showing in browser

Tags: html, css

I have set font-family to arial, Helvetica, sans-serif in internal css and it works fine in chrome.

When I save the css as external, the font on chrome changes to times new roman.

I’m fairly new to html/css... am I missing something? [HTML with External CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huoxa.png) [External CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6f2p.png) [How external CSS looks in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1yOV.png) [HTML with Internal CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6OiE.png) [Internal CSS on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imhnP.png)

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: @j08691 I’ve attached a few screenshots

Comment: I didn't ask for screenshots. I asked for a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Which page not set frontfamily, you can go this page chrome browser click ctl+u
, then go to view source file,then you click to you css frontfamily link . if file is not open your css frontfamily file, then you connect your frontfamily file properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your css path file is probably wrong and 'Times New Roman' is probably your default font's browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are many causes for this:

- The path for the CSS file is wrong.
- You loaded the font the wrong way
- You set the class the wrong way (`<div class=".clas">` instead of `<div class=".class">`)